# How to connect VPN L2TP/IPSEC

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, nmcli

we got a issue when attempt connect to vpn across to L2TP/IPSEC on Ubuntu 16.04.4 (DigitalOcean), we configure the Network Manager ($ nmcli) and install package 'Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol

[Network Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SunaM.png)

But when attempt connect the service stopped unexpectedly.

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSXiT.png)

Somebody can help me D= ?
Thanks.

---

In `/var/log/syslog` show this :

[syslog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu8Gn.png)

Comment: Have you actually *read* the error message?  You didn't provide the `--ask` argument to `nmcli` and you didn't have the PW set in the configuration for the VPN, so it can't get a password, and aborts.  You need to either have it ask for the login creds via `nmcli`, or define the credentials in the config.

Comment: Yes, I provide the `--ask` argument, however return the same `Error : Connection activation failed: the VPN service stopped unexpectedly.` or exist some one log where return all errors of nmcli or know the causes?, thanks